# Array works once, then never again after loop

Tags: php, arrays, actionscript-3, loops

I'm making an Flash Quiz where I extract data from PHP to use as questions and answers in my game. Everything imports just fine, but I'm having a problem with identifying the correct answer. The quiz is multiple choice, 4 possible answers. When you click an button it will activate my function -

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,returnAnswerOne);
function returnAnswerOne(event:Event){
answeredQuestion()
}
```

This works just fine. It activates the following function -

```
function answeredQuestion() {
    if(correctoneArray[numLoops] == 1){
        trace(correctoneArray[numLoops]);
        trace("right answer");
        gotoAndStop(4);
    } else { 
            trace(correctoneArray[numLoops]);
        trace("wrong answer");
        gotoAndStop(5);
    }
```

The way my flash knows if the answer is right is by seeing is the number '1' is present. My PHP output for the correct answer looks like this

```
&correctone=0/0/0/0/0/0/0/0 &correcttwo=0/1/0/0/1/0/1/0 &correctthree=1/0/1/0/0/0/0/1 &correctfour=0/0/0/1/0/1/0/0
```

This is the method I use to import these arrays which works just fine -

```
var loader3:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader3.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler2);
loader3.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
loader3.load(request);

function completeHandler2(event:Event) :void{
var correctone:String = event.target.data.correctone;
var correctoneArray:Array=correctone.split("/")
trace("Correctone Loaded");
```

Trying to refrain from spamming my entire script, so imagine there are 4 of these functions, each checking for '1'. Frame 5 is where you're told the question is wrong and frame 4 is where you are told the question is right. All the script posted above takes place on frame 3.

So *deep breathe* my problem is, this all works fine for the first question, but when I get on to question two ALL the answers are wrong when you click them and this continues throughout the entire quiz. Does anybody have any idea what could be going wrong? My trace shows that after question 1, all buttons produce the value 0.

If you need any additional info please let me know, this one has me stumped...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does the variable `numLoops` get set?

Comment: frame 1, but my questions and answers run in the same manner from numLoops and they seem to work just fine

Comment: Sorry, I mean: what does the code look like? What is the value of numLoops? Where does it get incremented?

Comment: 'var numLoops:Number = 0;' and it is incremented when a question is correct or incorrect so for example 'function gotoFrameFive (e:TimerEvent):void{
 numLoops++;
 delayTimer.stop();
 delayTimer.reset();
 delayTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,        gotoFrameFive);
 if(numLoops == 8) {
  this.gotoAndStop(6);
 } else {
  this.gotoAndStop(5);
 }
}'

Comment: Starting to think maybe numLoops has too much control...just noticed it is also being incremented as numLoops++ on frame 4, when I added it to frame 5 too question 2 still didn't work correctly, but surprisingly question 3 did. However the questions and answers stopped working. When I removed borh 'numLoops++' from both frame 4 and 5, everything stops working

Comment: I expect there is a flaw in your answer tracking logic, which is out of scope of provided code. You say you increment numLoops (BTW, why is it Number instead of int?) in separate places. You should check when this is called, probably via lots of traces, two traces should stand beside increments and report numLoops and place in code, like `trace("numLoops is",numLoops,"increased in gotoFrameFive");` and watch what portions of code are executed when you do something. Also, why `correctOne` is full of zeroes? Maybe this is unexpected in your program.

Comment: I will try you suggestions thank you. No particular reason why it's a Number instead of an int, just how I started out. correctone is full of 0's because answerone is never the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what's going wrong without seeing everything. Let me suggest you just tidy things up some. First, make use of the fact that you can refer to variables by name in order to avoid duplication all the code for the array parsing and button handlers. Second, make sure you only increment your question number in one place. Third, use more meaningful variable names.

All together, this should get you going:

**Note:**

- I've tweaked your frames so the Q&A buttons first appear on frame 3 but extend to frame 4. Now correct answer is on frame 5 and wrong answer is frame 6. This way you don't keep reloading the answers and recreating the event handlers every time you return to frame *4*.
- I'm assuming your answer buttons are named 'button1', 'button2', etc.

```js
// ----------------------------- FRAME 1 -----------------------------//
// Declare answers array and questionNumber counter
var answers:Array = [];
var questionNumber:int = 0;

// ----------------------------- FRAME 3 -----------------------------//
//  Just load the answers and hook up the  event handlers
// -------------------------------------------------------------------//

// Load the answers 
var answerKeyLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
answerKeyLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, answerKeyCompleteHandler);
answerKeyLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
answerKeyLoader.load(request);

function answerKeyCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
    var numberNames:Object = { one:1, two:2, three:3, four:4 };
    for(var nName:* in numberNames) {
        var index:int = numberNames[nName];
        var answerString:String = e.target.data["correct" + nName];
        answers[index] = answerString.split("/");
    }
}

// Attach button handlers (all buttons can use the same handler)
for(var i:uint = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    var button:DisplayObject = this["button" + i.toString()];
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickAnswerButton);
}

function onClickAnswerButton(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var buttonName:String = DisplayObject(e.currentTarget).name;
    var buttonNumber:int = int(buttonName.substring(6,1));
    var correct:Boolean = answers[buttonNumber][questionNumber] == 1;
    // Double check:
    trace("buttonName =", buttonName, ", buttonNumber =",buttonNumber,
          ", questionNumber =", questionNumber, ", correct =", correct);

    // Increment questionNumber here and nowhere else
    questionNumber++;
    if(correct) {
        trace("right answer");
        gotoAndStop(5);
    } else{
        trace("wrong answer");
        gotoAndStop(6);
    }
}

// ----------------------------- FRAME 4 -----------------------------//
//  Just show the new question
// -------------------------------------------------------------------//
someLabel.text = questions[questionNumber];
stop();

// ----------------------------- FRAME 5 -----------------------------//
someButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickButton);
function onClickButton(e:MouseEvent):void {
    someButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickButton);
    goToAndPlay(4);
}

// ----------------------------- FRAME 6 -----------------------------//
someButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickButton);
function onClickButton(e:MouseEvent):void {
    someButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickButton);
    goToAndPlay(4);
}
```

Comment: wow this looks great! Thank you very much for your time, will try making all these amends now and let you know how I get on

Comment: Hi Jmh_gr, just wanted to let you know my game is functioning b-e-a-u-tifully now, thank you again for your help